# iBeacon バックグラウンドで検知したビーコンの major と minor を知る方法はありますか？

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

## バックグランドで検知したビーコンの major と minor を知りたい

---

バックグラウンド処理では RangingBeaconsInRegion が使えないので MonitoringForRegion を使って検知をしていますが、MonitoringForRegion では UUID しかわからず major と minor がわかりません。

バックグラウンドでも major と minor を知る方法がないかを探しています。

もし MonitoringForRegion でも major と minor を取る方法か、代替手段があれば教えていただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/112882

Comment: マルチポストのご指摘ですが、テラテイルとここでは読む方が違うのと、色々な意見が欲しかったため、両方に投稿しております。
解決した情報は、どちらにも反映しております。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答しようとする方への情報提供ですので、質問者さんはお気になさらず。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決になりますが無事解決できました。

---

initWithProximity で UUID の他に major と minor を指定することで、MonitoringForRegion でも major と minor を取得することができました。

もし同様なことでお困りの方のご参考になれば幸いです